# SyntaxError in Jison parser

Tags: javascript, bison, flex-lexer, jison

I'm trying to write a parser using [Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/docs/) that'll parse the output of the `javap` tool.  Here's  the contents of my .jison file:

```
%lex

%x classfile

%%

"Classfile"             { this.begin("classfile"); }

<classfile>\s+          { /* ignore whitespace */ }
<classfile>[^\n]+       { this.popState(); return 'CLASSFILE'; }

<INITIAL><<EOF>>        { return 'EOF'; }

/lex

%start root

%%

root
  : CLASSFILE EOF { return $1; }
  ;
```

Unfortunately, when I run "jison javap.jison", I get this error:

```
undefined:5
case 0:"Classfile"             { this.begin("classfile"); }
                               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Function (<anonymous>)
    at Object.buildActions (C:\Users\cdmck_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jison\node_modules\jison-lex\regexp-lexer.js:118:12)
    at Object.RegExpLexer (C:\Users\cdmck_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jison\node_modules\jison-lex\regexp-lexer.js:131:39)
    at Jison_Generator (C:\Users\cdmck_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jison\lib\jison.js:108:22)
    at (anonymous function) (C:\Users\cdmck_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jison\lib\util\typal.js:23:28)
    at new o.constructor (C:\Users\cdmck_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jison\lib\util\typal.js:77:70)
    at new Jison_Generator (C:\Users\cdmck_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jison\lib\jison.js:1578:20)
    at processGrammar (C:\Users\cdmck_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jison\lib\cli.js:87:21)
    at Object.exports.main (C:\Users\cdmck_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jison\lib\cli.js:61:56)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cdmck_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jison\lib\cli.js:105:13)
```

I've tried replacing `"Classfile"` with `\w+` but then it just gives me an error at the `\` of `\w+` instead.

Comment: Looks like Jison might be broken: https://github.com/zaach/jison/issues/152

Comment: I downgraded to 0.3.12. The `calculator.jison` parser builds now, but  I still get the same error for mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted the line endings to UNIX format from Windows format and the problem went away.